# Using Pattern to create regex code for validation

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to make this regex work for my input field. The idea is to create one input field which would have a sort of code validation.

my code:

```
  <input type="number" class="container_input sort-code" placeholder="Sortcode" pattern="/(?!(?:0{6}|00-00-00))(?:\d{6}|\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)/" title="Numbers only eg 11-11-11" required>
```

Comment: What are the rules for a valid sort code?

Comment: Thats what I want to find out.